# keep the first timestamp of a specific list

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
dframe <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), name = c("Google", 
    "Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Google", "Amazon"), date = c("2008-11-01", 
    "2008-11-02", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02", 
    "2008-11-03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

And a list with names

```
list <- c("Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon")
```

How can I have an output like this:

> ```
> id   name       date
> 1 Google 2008-11-01
> 1  Yahoo 2008-11-01
> 1 Amazon 2008-11-04
> 2 Amazon 2008-11-01
> 2 Google 2008-11-02
> ```

For every id keep from the list the first date. I tried this one:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)
date_list_first= dframe[,head(.SD,1), by = .(id)]
```

Comment: `dframe %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  slice(1L)
` using `dplyr`

Comment: Does the column `name` only has the names from the list or are there others not included in your `list`. Note..don't name your objects with predefined functions. `list` is a base R function

Comment: Maybe something like `dframe[(!duplicated(dframe[c("id","name")])) & dframe$name %in% list,]` if you need to remove dups and only keep those in the specified list.

Comment: @Sotos name column includes the same names as the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dframe)
date_list_first = dframe[order(date)][!duplicated(id,by=c('name','id'))]
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not as the expected output. I want to keep all from list from their first date

Comment: Ah, now I understand: for each combination of id and name, you want to keep the row with the earliest date. Fixed.