# Keep values from a list based on the first timestamp record

Tags: r, date, filter

I would like to keep from an external list:

```
list <- c("Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon")
```

The values in the dataframe which have record in the first timestamp (the most old timestamp) in data like this:

```
dframe <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), name = c("Google", 
    "Google", "Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Google", "Amazon"), date = c("2008-11-01", 
    "2008-11-02", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02", 
    "2008-11-03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

The expected output is this:

> ```
> id   name       date
> 1 Google 2008-11-01
> 1  Yahoo 2008-11-01
> 1 Amazon 2008-11-04
> 2 Amazon 2008-11-01
> 2 Google 2008-11-02
> ```

How is it possible to make it?

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131516/11786778) it keep only the first record for every id and not for every single value from the list which recorded first time in time

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dframe)
date_list_first = dframe[order(date)][!duplicated(id)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `base R`

```
dframe$date <- as.Date(dframe$date)
aggregate(date~ ., dframe, min)
#  id   name       date
#1  1 Amazon 2008-11-04
#2  2 Amazon 2008-11-01
#3  1 Google 2008-11-01
#4  2 Google 2008-11-02
#5  1  Yahoo 2008-11-01
```

Comment: Any idea for this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141008/keep-before-and-after-date-of-an-external-list ?

Answer (score 5):

Using data.table:

```
dframe = data.table(dframe)
dframe[, date := as.Date(date)]

dt = dframe[, .(date = min(date)), .(id, name)]

> dt
   id   name       date
1:  1 Google 2008-11-01
2:  1  Yahoo 2008-11-01
3:  1 Amazon 2008-11-04
4:  2 Amazon 2008-11-01
5:  2 Google 2008-11-02
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it in `dplyr`:

```
dframe %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
group_by(id, name) %>% summarise(date = min(date)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Nothing fancy really, just group and summarize.

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     id name   date      
  <int> <chr>  <date>    
1     1 Amazon 2008-11-04
2     1 Google 2008-11-01
3     1 Yahoo  2008-11-01
4     2 Amazon 2008-11-01
5     2 Google 2008-11-02
```